# Not an ARRAY reference error in "pop($str)"

Tags: perl

I am learning Perl for work and I'm trying to practise with some basic programs.

I want my program to take a string from STDIN and modify it by taking the last character and putting it at the start of the string.

I get an error when I use variable `$str` in `$str = <STDIN>`.

Here is my code:

```perl
my $str = "\0";
$str = <STDIN>;

sub last_to_first {
    chomp($str);
    pop($str);
    print $str;
}

last_to_first;
```

Exec :

```
Matrix :hi
Not an ARRAY reference at matrix.pl line 13, <STDIN> line 1.
```

Comment: `pop()` is for arrays only, and you don't have an array. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html

Comment: You can't use pop function in Scalar variables.

Comment: Your first lesson is that the language is called ***Perl***; the second is that you *must always* start *every* Perl program with `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`, and indent your code by four spaces inside blocks so that the structure is clear.

Comment: Perl is not C. Strings are not arrays. Also, Perl strings can have multiple embedded `NUL`s in them. `"\0"` is not an empty string.

Comment: `chop` does what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Why your approach doesn't work**

The [`pop` keyword](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html) does not work on strings. Strings in Perl are not automatically cast to character arrays, and those array keywords only work on arrays.

The error message is *Not an ARRAY reference* because `pop` sees a scalar variable. References are scalars in Perl (the scalar here is something like a reference to the address of the actual array in memory). The `pop` built-in [takes array references](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.24.0/functions/pop.html) in Perl versions between 5.14 and 5.22. It was experimental, [but got removed in the (currently latest) 5.24](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.24.0/perldelta.html#The-autoderef-feature-has-been-removed).

> Starting with Perl 5.14, an experimental feature allowed pop to take a scalar expression. This experiment has been deemed unsuccessful, and was removed as of Perl 5.24.

**How to make it work**

You have to [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) your string first.

```
my $str = 'foo';

# turn it into an array
my @chars = split //, $str;

# remove the last char and put it at the front
unshift @chars, pop @chars;

# turn it back into a string
$str = join '', @chars;

print $str;
```

That will give you `ofo`.

Now to use that as a sub, you should pass a parameter. Otherwise you do not need a subroutine.

```
sub last_to_first {
    my $str = shift;

    my @chars = split //, $str;
    unshift @chars, pop @chars;
    $str = join '', @chars;

    return $str;
}
```

You can call that sub with any string argument. You should do the `chomp` to remove the trailing newline from STDIN outside of the sub, because it is not needed for switching the chars. Always build your subs in the smallest possible *unit* to make it easy to debug them. One piece of code should do exactly one functionality.

You also do not need to initialize a string with `\0`. In fact, that doesn't make sense.

Here's a full program.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $str = <STDIN>;
chomp $str;

print last_to_first($str);

sub last_to_first {
    my $str = shift;

    my @chars = split //, $str;
    unshift @chars, pop @chars;
    $str = join '', @chars;

    return $str;
}
```

**Testing your program**

Because you now have one *unit* in your `last_to_first` function, you can easily implement a unit test. Perl brings [Test::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Simple) and [Test::More](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More) (and other tools) for that purpose. Because this is simple, we'll go with Test::Simple.

You load it, tell it how many tests you are going to do, and then use the `ok` function. Ideally you would put the stuff you want to test into its own module, but for simplicity I'll have it all in the same program.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use Test::Simple tests => 3;

ok last_to_first('foo', 'ofo');
ok last_to_first('123', '321');
ok last_to_first('qqqqqq', 'qqqqqq');

sub last_to_first {
    my $str = shift;

    my @chars = split //, $str;
    unshift @chars, pop @chars;
    $str = join '', @chars;

    return $str;
}
```

This will output the following:

```
1..3
ok 1
ok 2
ok 3
```

Run it with `prove` instead of `perl` to get a bit more comprehensive output.

**Refactoring it**

Now let's change the implementation of `last_to_first` to use a [regular expression substitution with `s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) instead of the array approach.

```
sub last_to_first {
    my $str = shift;

    $str =~ s/^(.+)(.)$/$2$1/;

    return $str;
}
```

This code uses a pattern match with two groups `()`. The first one has a lot of chars after the beginning of the string `^`, and the second one has exactly one char, after which the string ends `$`. You can check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/hB0aR2/1). Those groups end up in `$1` and `$2`, and all we need to do is switch them around.

If you replace your function in the program with the test, and then run it, the output will be the same. You have just refactored one of the units in your program.

You can also try the `substr` approach from [zdim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38869728/1331451) with this test, and you will see that the tests still pass.

Comment: `substr $str, 0, 0, substr $str, -1, 1, ""` or perhaps not!

Answer (score 1):

The core function [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html) takes an array, and removes and returns its last element.

To manipulate characters in a string you can use [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html), for example

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = <STDIN>;
chomp($str);

my $last_char = substr $str, -1, 1, '';
my $new_str = $last_char . $str;
```

The arguments to `substr` mean: search the variable `$str`, at offset `-1` (one from the back), for a substring of length `1`, and replace that with an empty string `''` (thus removing it).  The substring that is found, here the last character, is returned. See the documentation page linked above.

In the last line the returned character is concatenated with the remaining string, using the `.` operator.

---

You can browse the list of functions broken down by categories at [`Perl functions by category`](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-functions-by-cat.html).
Perl documentation has a lot of goodies, please look around.

Strings are very often manipulated using *regular expressions*.  See the tutorial [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), the quick start [`perlrequick`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html), the quick reference [`perlreref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html), and the full reference [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

You can also split a string into a character array and work with that. This is shown in detail in the [answer by simbabque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38869720/4653379), which packs a whole lot more of good advice.

Comment: TIMTOWTDI :) - but those keywords are called _built-ins_, not _library functions_ in Perl

Comment: An alternative solution using the ARGV variable instead of <STDIN> :  
  
`use strict;  
use warnings;  

my $str = $ARGV[0];  
my $last_char = substr $str, -1;  
print my $new_str = "$last_char"."$str";`

Comment: @Baptiste actually that's not an alternative, because `@ARGV` contains the command line arguments, and not `STDIN`. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: @simbabque Indeed they are, but when people are just starting a generic term may make it clearer.

Comment: @simbabque  And indeed, TIMTOWTDI -- and it came out well :)

Comment: And you could do it in one line by using `substr` as an lvalue too. `substr( $str, 0 ) = substr( $str, -1, 1, q{} );`.

Comment: @simbabque  I typed in something very similar in there ... and removed it.  I think that it isn't the best advice for someone just starting.

Comment: I agree. The extra step is way easier to understand. Just wanted to add it for completeness since we were talking about TIMTOWTDI. ;)

Comment: I'm surprised how much "*library function*" jars and I think it means pretty much the opposite of what you intend. (Library books are books that you check out because you don't have them on your shelf at home.) I prefer *operator*, *core function*, or *built-in* and I don't think a beginner would have an issue with any of those except Perl's unusual use of "operator".

Comment: @Borodin Great, _core function_ is it. Thank you. What I used has been bothering me as well. (I normally never use that in Perl. I think that it was the desire for a generic term that sneaked it in.)

Answer (score 0):

This is for substring function used for array variables:

```
my @arrays = qw(jan feb mar); 
last_to_first(@arrays);

sub last_to_first
{
    my @lists = @_;
    my $last = pop(@lists);
    #print $last;
    unshift @lists, $last;
    print @lists;
}
```

This is for substring function used for scalar variables:

```
my $str = "";
$str = <STDIN>;
chomp ($str);

last_to_first($str);

sub last_to_first
{
    my $chr = shift;
    my $lastchar = substr($chr, -1);
    print $lastchar;
}
```